# decode ethereum input data in R

Tags: decoding

I am using the etherscan API to get the input data of transactions. However I have no real clue how I can  decode the input data into something readable.

For example:

`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`

Do I need additional information to decode this? Is there package to simplify this?

Thanks

EDIT: so this is a transaction interacting with a uniswap smart contract https://etherscan.io/tx/0x63dc5aea1c999e4256a58eaad7d39c2b24bf359e76c29bef89e9e758ffa5224e

`Function: swapExactTokensForETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(uint256 amountIn, uint256 amountOutMin, address[] path, address to, uint256 deadline)`

Comment: Please provide some more context. How exactly did you get this data? Where did you get it from? What network are you connected to? What contract address this transaction belongs to?

Comment: It is on ETH mainnet and I got it by using the Etherscan API in my R program.

So this is a transaction interacting with a uniswap smart contract https://etherscan.io/tx/0x63dc5aea1c999e4256a58eaad7d39c2b24bf359e76c29bef89e9e758ffa5224e

Answer (score 1):

You definitely need additional information to decode this data. The information you need is called the ABI which describes the format of the input data. The ABI is generated from the source code and if you have the source, you can generate the ABI using something like remix or Truffle.

If you don't have the source, you still may be able to get the ABI if you know the smart contract to which the transition was sent (you probably do). In that case, you can go to Ehterscan and look at the Contract tab for that address (if the address is a contract). At the bottom of the contract tab, you will find the ABI.

You could also fake an ABI by going to the Etheruem 4byte registry (search it) and creating the ABI by hand (I suppose -- last resort).

Once you have the ABI, then you'll need to decode the input data. The easiest way to do that would be to use something like web3.js or ethers.js which take an ABI and the input and extract the values.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, this already helps alot. So this is a transaction interacting with a uniswap smart contract https://etherscan.io/tx/0x63dc5aea1c999e4256a58eaad7d39c2b24bf359e76c29bef89e9e758ffa5224e

would this already qualify as ABI: 
```Function: swapExactTokensForETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(uint256 amountIn, uint256 amountOutMin, address[] path, address to, uint256 deadline)```

since I am coding in R using web3.js is not an option (or is it? I am not that experienced)

Comment: Yes. So the parameters for that function call are encoded In the input data. web3.js allows you to decode that byte string. There’s probably no library in R for doing that decoding, so that’s your task.  If you do find a library, come back here and post its location so others can find it.

Comment: You are right, this gives the answer. But for some reason decoding work only for some transactions. I made separate post about this problem here https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/144517/abi-decoder-decode-params-from-data-of-uniswap-transaction.