# abi-decoder decode params from data of uniswap transaction

Tags: ethers.js, uniswap, decoding

I could decode data for one transaction normally, but I can not for other. I am attaching both examples. I have no clue why the second one doesn't work because it seems I am doing the same yet it won't show token information. I would appreciate if anybody could take a look, compare both examples and if you see what could be wrong. I get INPUT_DATA from ethers function getTransaction.

Working example from [this tx](https://polygonscan.com/tx/0x73eb209195b93fc25bc3957fca9b373ca82c12905f81cd564b310034e622db18):

```
var ethers = require("ethers");
var abiDecoder = require('abi-decoder');
ABI = [{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"_factory","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"_WETH9","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"_tokenDescriptor_","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"constructor"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"owner","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"approved","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"uint256","name":"tokenId","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Approval","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"owner","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"operator","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"bool","name":"approved","type":"bool"}],"name":"ApprovalForAll","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"uint256","name":"tokenId","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"address","name":"recipient","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount0","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount1","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Collect","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"uint256","name":"tokenId","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint128","name":"liquidity","type":"uint128"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount0","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount1","type":"uint256"}],"name":"DecreaseLiquidity","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"uint256","name":"tokenId","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint128","name":"liquidity","type":"uint128"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount0","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount1","type":"uint256"}],"name":"IncreaseLiquidity","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"from","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"uint256","name":"tokenId","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Transfer","type":"event"},{"inputs":[],"name":"DOMAIN_SEPARATOR","outputs":[{"internalType":"bytes32","name":"","type":"bytes32"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"PERMIT_TYPEHASH","outputs":[{"internalType":"bytes32","name":"","type":"bytes32"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"WETH9","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"tokenId","type":"uint256"}],"name":"approve","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"owner","type":"address"}],"name":"balanceOf","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"baseURI","outputs":[{"internalType":"string","name":"","type":"string"}],"stateMutability":"pure","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"tokenId","type":"uint256"}],"name":"burn","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"components":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"tokenId","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address","name":"recipient","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint128","name":"amount0Max","type":"uint128"},{"internalType":"uint128","name":"amount1Max","type":"uint128"}],"internalType":"struct INonfungiblePositionManager.CollectParams","name":"params","type":"tuple"}],"name":"collect","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount0","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount1","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"token0","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"token1","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint24","name":"fee","type":"uint24"},{"internalType":"uint160","name":"sqrtPriceX96","type":"uint160"}],"name":"createAndInitializePoolIfNecessary","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"pool","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"components":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"tokenId","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint128","name":"liquidity","type":"uint128"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount0Min","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount1Min","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"deadline","type":"uint256"}],"internalType":"struct INonfungiblePositionManager.DecreaseLiquidityParams","name":"params","type":"tuple"}],"name":"decreaseLiquidity","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount0","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount1","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"factory","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"tokenId","type":"uint256"}],"name":"getApproved","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"components":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"tokenId","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount0Desired","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount1Desired","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount0Min","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount1Min","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"deadline","type":"uint256"}],"internalType":"struct INonfungiblePositionManager.IncreaseLiquidityParams","name":"params","type":"tuple"}],"name":"increaseLiquidity","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint128","name":"liquidity","type":"uint128"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount0","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount1","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"owner","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"operator","type":"address"}],"name":"isApprovedForAll","outputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"","type":"bool"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"components":[{"internalType":"address","name":"token0","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"token1","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint24","name":"fee","type":"uint24"},{"internalType":"int24","name":"tickLower","type":"int24"},{"internalType":"int24","name":"tickUpper","type":"int24"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount0Desired","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount1Desired","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount0Min","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount1Min","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address","name":"recipient","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"deadline","type":"uint256"}],"internalType":"struct INonfungiblePositionManager.MintParams","name":"params","type":"tuple"}],"name":"mint","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"tokenId","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint128","name":"liquidity","type":"uint128"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount0","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount1","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"bytes[]","name":"data","type":"bytes[]"}],"name":"multicall","outputs":[{"internalType":"bytes[]","name":"results","type":"bytes[]"}],"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"name","outputs":[{"internalType":"string","name":"","type":"string"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"tokenId","type":"uint256"}],"name":"ownerOf","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"spender","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"tokenId","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"deadline","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint8","name":"v","type":"uint8"},{"internalType":"bytes32","name":"r","type":"bytes32"},{"internalType":"bytes32","name":"s","type":"bytes32"}],"name":"permit","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"tokenId","type":"uint256"}],"name":"positions","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint96","name":"nonce","type":"uint96"},{"internalType":"address","name":"operator","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"token0","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"token1","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint24","name":"fee","type":"uint24"},{"internalType":"int24","name":"tickLower","type":"int24"},{"internalType":"int24","name":"tickUpper","type":"int24"},{"internalType":"uint128","name":"liquidity","type":"uint128"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"feeGrowthInside0LastX128","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"feeGrowthInside1LastX128","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint128","name":"tokensOwed0","type":"uint128"},{"internalType":"uint128","name":"tokensOwed1","type":"uint128"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"refundETH","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"from","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"tokenId","type":"uint256"}],"name":"safeTransferFrom","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"from","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"tokenId","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"bytes","name":"_data","type":"bytes"}],"name":"safeTransferFrom","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"token","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"value","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"deadline","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint8","name":"v","type":"uint8"},{"internalType":"bytes32","name":"r","type":"bytes32"},{"internalType":"bytes32","name":"s","type":"bytes32"}],"name":"selfPermit","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"token","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"nonce","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"expiry","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint8","name":"v","type":"uint8"},{"internalType":"bytes32","name":"r","type":"bytes32"},{"internalType":"bytes32","name":"s","type":"bytes32"}],"name":"selfPermitAllowed","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"token","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"nonce","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"expiry","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint8","name":"v","type":"uint8"},{"internalType":"bytes32","name":"r","type":"bytes32"},{"internalType":"bytes32","name":"s","type":"bytes32"}],"name":"selfPermitAllowedIfNecessary","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"token","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"value","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"deadline","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint8","name":"v","type":"uint8"},{"internalType":"bytes32","name":"r","type":"bytes32"},{"internalType":"bytes32","name":"s","type":"bytes32"}],"name":"selfPermitIfNecessary","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"operator","type":"address"},{"internalType":"bool","name":"approved","type":"bool"}],"name":"setApprovalForAll","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"bytes4","name":"interfaceId","type":"bytes4"}],"name":"supportsInterface","outputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"","type":"bool"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"token","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountMinimum","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address","name":"recipient","type":"address"}],"name":"sweepToken","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"symbol","outputs":[{"internalType":"string","name":"","type":"string"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"index","type":"uint256"}],"name":"tokenByIndex","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"owner","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"index","type":"uint256"}],"name":"tokenOfOwnerByIndex","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"tokenId","type":"uint256"}],"name":"tokenURI","outputs":[{"internalType":"string","name":"","type":"string"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"totalSupply","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"from","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"tokenId","type":"uint256"}],"name":"transferFrom","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount0Owed","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount1Owed","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"bytes","name":"data","type":"bytes"}],"name":"uniswapV3MintCallback","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountMinimum","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address","name":"recipient","type":"address"}],"name":"unwrapWETH9","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"},{"stateMutability":"payable","type":"receive"}]
;
const INPUT_DATA ="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";
  
abiDecoder.addABI(ABI);
const decodeMulticall = abiDecoder.decodeMethod(INPUT_DATA);
  
console.log("decodeMulticall", JSON.stringify(decodeMulticall, null, 1));
const decodeParamsValue = abiDecoder.decodeMethod(
    decodeMulticall.params[0].value[0]
);
console.log("FINAL OUTPUT", decodeParamsValue);
```

It shows proper information:

```
decodeMulticall {
 "name": "multicall",
 "params": [
  {
   "name": "data",
   "value": [
    "0x13ead5620000000000000000000000005c8cd1c2f2997f7a041026cc29de8177b4c6d8ec00000000000000000000000089e54f174ca5ff39cf53ab58004158e2ca012eac0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000bb8000000000000000000000000000000000035f2482336c0d4c2ba6e94faa1d66f",
    "0x883164560000000000000000000000005c8cd1c2f2997f7a041026cc29de8177b4c6d8ec00000000000000000000000089e54f174ca5ff39cf53ab58004158e2ca012eac0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000bb8fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff2764c00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000a11a8000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000e8d4a510000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000a56d35c029fd16645e079000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000e840308c030000000000000000000000000000000000000000000a503344abc0fbe23670910000000000000000000000005a2b5cb4ce921abd65f0c66c2c839894bfc2076c000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006244356a"   ],
   "type": "bytes[]"
  }
 ]
}
FINAL OUTPUT {
  name: 'createAndInitializePoolIfNecessary',
  params: [
    {
      name: 'token0',
      value: '0x5c8cd1c2f2997f7a041026cc29de8177b4c6d8ec',
      type: 'address'
    },
    {
      name: 'token1',
      value: '0x89e54f174ca5ff39cf53ab58004158e2ca012eac',
      type: 'address'
    },
    { name: 'fee', value: '3000', type: 'uint24' },
    {
      name: 'sqrtPriceX96',
      value: '280105791952298552699389429697074799',
      type: 'uint160'
    }
  ]
}
```

Not working from [this tx](https://goerli.etherscan.io/tx/0xd885cbf09b8d29498d127854a726647915c385b7018dfff2d8c26756fa8469f2):

```
var ethers = require("ethers");
var abiDecoder = require('abi-decoder');

var ABI = [{"inputs":[{"components":[{"internalType":"address","name":"permit2","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"weth9","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"seaport","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"nftxZap","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"x2y2","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"foundation","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"sudoswap","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"nft20Zap","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"cryptopunks","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"looksRare","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"routerRewardsDistributor","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"looksRareRewardsDistributor","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"looksRareToken","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"v2Factory","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"v3Factory","type":"address"},{"internalType":"bytes32","name":"pairInitCodeHash","type":"bytes32"},{"internalType":"bytes32","name":"poolInitCodeHash","type":"bytes32"}],"internalType":"struct RouterParameters","name":"params","type":"tuple"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"constructor"},{"inputs":[],"name":"ContractLocked","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"ETHNotAccepted","type":"error"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"commandIndex","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"bytes","name":"message","type":"bytes"}],"name":"ExecutionFailed","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"FromAddressIsNotOwner","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"InsufficientETH","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"InsufficientToken","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"InvalidBips","type":"error"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"commandType","type":"uint256"}],"name":"InvalidCommandType","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"InvalidOwnerERC1155","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"InvalidOwnerERC721","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"InvalidPath","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"InvalidReserves","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"LengthMismatch","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"NoSlice","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"SliceOutOfBounds","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"SliceOverflow","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"ToAddressOutOfBounds","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"ToAddressOverflow","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"ToUint24OutOfBounds","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"ToUint24Overflow","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"TransactionDeadlinePassed","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"UnableToClaim","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"UnsafeCast","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"V2InvalidPath","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"V2TooLittleReceived","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"V2TooMuchRequested","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"V3InvalidAmountOut","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"V3InvalidCaller","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"V3InvalidSwap","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"V3TooLittleReceived","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"V3TooMuchRequested","type":"error"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"RewardsSent","type":"event"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"bytes","name":"looksRareClaim","type":"bytes"}],"name":"collectRewards","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"bytes","name":"commands","type":"bytes"},{"internalType":"bytes[]","name":"inputs","type":"bytes[]"}],"name":"execute","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"bytes","name":"commands","type":"bytes"},{"internalType":"bytes[]","name":"inputs","type":"bytes[]"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"deadline","type":"uint256"}],"name":"execute","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256[]","name":"","type":"uint256[]"},{"internalType":"uint256[]","name":"","type":"uint256[]"},{"internalType":"bytes","name":"","type":"bytes"}],"name":"onERC1155BatchReceived","outputs":[{"internalType":"bytes4","name":"","type":"bytes4"}],"stateMutability":"pure","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"bytes","name":"","type":"bytes"}],"name":"onERC1155Received","outputs":[{"internalType":"bytes4","name":"","type":"bytes4"}],"stateMutability":"pure","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"bytes","name":"","type":"bytes"}],"name":"onERC721Received","outputs":[{"internalType":"bytes4","name":"","type":"bytes4"}],"stateMutability":"pure","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"bytes4","name":"interfaceId","type":"bytes4"}],"name":"supportsInterface","outputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"","type":"bool"}],"stateMutability":"pure","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"int256","name":"amount0Delta","type":"int256"},{"internalType":"int256","name":"amount1Delta","type":"int256"},{"internalType":"bytes","name":"data","type":"bytes"}],"name":"uniswapV3SwapCallback","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"stateMutability":"payable","type":"receive"}]

const INPUT_DATA ="0x3593564c000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000a00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000063e372b800000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020b000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000a000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002386f26fc1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002386f26fc100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000022617836d5041c00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000a00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002bb4fbf271143f4fbf7b91a5ded31805e42b2208d60001f41f9840a85d5af5bf1d1762f925bdaddc4201f984000000000000000000000000000000000000000000";
  
abiDecoder.addABI(ABI);
const decodeMulticall = abiDecoder.decodeMethod(INPUT_DATA);
  
console.log("decodeMulticall", JSON.stringify(decodeMulticall, null, 1));
const decodeParamsValue = abiDecoder.decodeMethod(
decodeMulticall.params[0].value[0]
);
console.log("FINAL OUTPUT", decodeParamsValue);
```

It shows this:

```
decodeMulticall {
 "name": "execute",
 "params": [
  {
   "name": "commands",
   "value": "0x0b00",
   "type": "bytes"
  },
  {
   "name": "inputs",
   "value": [
    "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002386f26fc10000",
    "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"
   ],
   "type": "bytes[]"
  },
  {
   "name": "deadline",
   "value": "1675850424",
   "type": "uint256"
  }
 ]
}
FINAL OUTPUT undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

The first one is working because is an invocation of "multicall" function, that accepts a list of encoded input data for each of the call that should be done (as detailed in the smart contract source)

```
/// @param data The encoded function data for each of the calls to make to this contract
```

Then each input is passed to `delegatecall` function, so every encoded input is a complete call to a smart contract function.

So when you decode the input data of the 1st transaction, you get an array of encoded function calls, passing any of it to the decoder show you the decoded call.

The second one is not using encoded calls to make multiple call, but it's calling the "execute" function for each commands (first parameter)

```
/// @param commands A set of concatenated commands, each 1 byte in length
```

Then `execute` will call the `dispatch` function that will call internals function directly. Then input param contains only encoded inputs that will be passed to the command, and not a complete encoded function call